# Binding Error in my windows phone 8 project

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, binding

Well I am trying to do a simple binding in a Long list but the emulator is throwing a debug Exception in

private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)

I would paste my code below

My model class is

```
public class CommentView
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string IsApproved { get; set; }
    public string PostersComment { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  //Note that this is the name of the Jizuser
    public string PostedDate { get; set; }
    public string PostedTime { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing my binding from the xaml  csharp code. so the script is pasted below

```
 List<CommentView> commenterContainer = new List<CommentView>();
 commenterContainer.Add(new CommentView() { Name ="FEMI", IsApproved="True", ID="1", PostedDate="2/3/2014", PostedTime="01:02:2011", PostersComment= "Me" });
 commenterlist.ItemsSource = commenterContainer;
```

This is the longlist item. how I crafted the dataItem template

```
<phone:LongListSelector Margin="3"  x:Name="commenterlist" SelectionChanged ="Bloglist_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="6"
                                Background="White">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#4063A9">
                            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,10" Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>


                                    <Image Source="/Assets/profile.jpg"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#4063A9"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PostersComment}"  Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding PostedDate}"  />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding PostedTime}" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding IsApproved}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: feed us with the exception's message from e paramter

Comment: ok I would just a minute. thanks for your reply

Comment: Sadly Vs did not show me the error. It just place a break point in the App.xaml.cs file. at the line   Debugger.Break();    which is inside the  Application_UnhandledException method. I dont really no what the exception is but I know it is my Binding that is the problem

Comment: The event arg in the unhandled exception event doesn't have the exception? Failed bindings usually just report to the debug console.

Comment: ok, so I should past the content of the debug console

Comment: The problem I am begining to detect is from the LongListSelector xml there a line of code that is not making the binding to work. I just replaced it with another of my LongListSelector and I dont see the exception again

Comment: I have been able to solve the problem. But I really didnt identify it. I simply deleted my long list item and recreated it. and the application worked very fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was from the LongListSelector

Recreating the LongListSelector Solves the issue. I did this and it works fine